# Memory leak in MvxBaseViewController in MvvmCross-iOSSupport?

Tags: memory-management, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MvxBaseViewController from the iOS Support Library for keyboard handling.

By overriding dispose, I noticed that my view that inherits from MvxBaseViewController is not being collected by the GC when it is popped from the Navigationcontroller.

When I add the following in MvxBaseViewController...

```
public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

        this.UnregisterForKeyboardNotifications();

        this.View.RemoveGestureRecognizer(this.tap);
    }
```

... and when I add/remove the ShouldReturn delegate in my view like this...

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    this.myTextField.ShouldReturn += this.TextFieldShouldReturn;
}

public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
    this.myTextField.ShouldReturn -= this.TextFieldShouldReturn;
}
```

..then my view gets disposed.

I'm a beginner with MvvmCross and memory management in Xamarin, so my questions are:

Do I have any drawbacks with this workarounds? Is this the right way of handling this issue?